# Using redirect and rewrite with .htaccess for QR code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, qr-code

I have a bit of an interesting issue, I have a QR code that upon being scanned sends users to the address below:

```
enzymedica.org/ls/27210
```

(This is just the DEV site by the way the real one is .com)

Then I have it successfully redirecting to this address:

```
enzymedica.org/education/digestive/digest-gold.html
```

Now here is where the problem comes into play, if this is all it did then we wouldn't have a problem, however when the QR code gets scanned it tacks on a "?" and then a number like 0000 after it.

So in reality the url that you get sent to is more or less like this:

```
http://www.enzymedica.org/ls/27210?0000
```

and upon redirecting you get this:

```
http://www.enzymedica.org/education/digestive/digest-gold.html?0000
```

So I need some way to get the url rewritten to end at ".html" and not show anything after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+\.html)\?.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
```

The above will check if `education/digestive/anythinghere.html` have a query string, if it does it will redirect without the query string.

Or if you want a exact redirect of that URL you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(education/digestive/digest-gold\.html)$ /$1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Or if you want to eliminate it at the `ls/id` level:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^ls/([0-9]+)/?$ /ls/$1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am still ending up with a "?whatever" at the end of my url.

I don't know if this makes a difference or not, but I noticed that the url I provided is not the right one.

It is actually using this url:
http://www.enzymedica.org/ls/27210/?0000

Thanks,
John

Comment: @user2796828 well then you may have other rules that are conflicting with it as the above is set to specifically remove the query string when present.

Comment: Could the redirect rule be interfering?

Comment: @user2796828 also which of the 3 rules are you trying?

Comment: I have tried all of them, however I believe that the top one would be the best suited.

Comment: yes, however the top one will only remove the query string from the page itself. Is that a WordPress URL or any other CMS?

Comment: @user2796828 see the first rule again I have updated it and should work for joomla.